# Is there a way to trigger an event when inserting html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

It's for a backbone application, 
I'm using Jquery html() function to insert my views templates into the layout everywhere, and I would like to be able to trigger an event each time the html() function of jQuery is called to check the html of the page.

Is there a way to do that ?
( Like App.on('html', blablabla...); )

Thank you !

Comment: There's DOM MutationEvents, but they're not widely supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marc B suggested DOM MutationEvents is available on some browsers (not many). By default jQuery does not fire any event when using `html`, but you can define your own behaviour for this, for example:

```
(function($) {
    var html_ref = $.fn.html;
    $.fn.extend({
        html : function() {
            $(document).trigger( 'html_change' );
            return html_ref.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
})($);
```

It should work, didn't test it though. You can use the same with `.text` method. Now you can simply use:

```
$(document).bind( 'html_change', function() {
    // Hurray! Html changed!
});
```

That's the idea, use it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the jQuery `html()` method doesn't fire any subscribable events per se, but you could probably roll your own implementation of a simple [Observer pattern](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/).  I use this across a large number of projects and it provides a great, clean, lightweight way to encapsulate arbitrary event handling across loosely-coupled modules.

**However,** this is presuming that you have programmatic control over every time the `html()` method is called - if not, then this would be more difficult, as there is no callback function to hook into.